# Packages not found when upgrading from VS2013 to VS2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, teamcity

I have a project that previously been developed in VS2013. In this project I have references to NuGet packages that's in my TeamCity NuGet feed. When I opened my solution in VS2015, references to my packages were broken and I was unable to build the project. When I reinstall packages, it builds successfully. Reinstallation of the package makes some changes in .csproj file. Here are they:

```
<Reference Include="Logstream.Kofax.WorkflowAPI, Version=1.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
- <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Logstream.Kofax.WorkflowAPI.1.1.3.0\lib\net40\Logstream.Kofax.WorkflowAPI.dll</HintPath>
+ <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Logstream.Kofax.WorkflowAPI.1.1.3\lib\net40\Logstream.Kofax.WorkflowAPI.dll</HintPath>
```

As you can see, part of folder name of the package has changed from `1.1.3.0` to `1.1.3`.

Why do this happen? Do VS2013 and VS2015 treat package version numbers differently?

Comment: They shouldn't. By 'my TeamCity NuGet feed' do you mean you're hosting your own NuGet Gallery?

Comment: Yes, I'm using TeamCity as additional packages source.

Comment: When I first learned how to create NuGet packages, I remember reading that they should only use 3 version numbers, not 4. Is it possible that VS is stripping the zero, treating it as non-significant?